# Naming conventions when creating a PHP composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

I am creating a package that is loaded by PHP composer. I was planning to name the package just as my name shows along with the name of the class: `eComEvo/TestableAPI`

However, before I do so, could the use of capitals the way I have them create an issue with autoloading through composer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Composer suggests using only lowercase letters for the names. This might be related to the several file systems being possibly case-insensitive or not.

If you look at packagist.org, you only see lower case package names.

Answer (score 6):

all lowercase and dashes for word separation.

See the answer on [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#every-project-is-a-package)

Abstract:

> If you don't know what to use as a vendor name, your GitHub username
>   is usually a good bet. While package names are case insensitive, the
>   convention is all lowercase and dashes for word separation.